# Uploading Files to Google Cloud Storage via Google App Engine using Java: (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a Spring-MAVEN JAVA project(mostly REST APIs for backend) using GAE. I am also using GCS(Google Cloud Storage) for storing some images and videos. The problem is that when I execute my files in a local server(tomcat 8.0), it works perfectly and uploads files to GCS as well.

However, when I deploy the files to GAE and execute, it returns **java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory) error**.
I guess the GAE server cannot find files from my computer.

I've tried many things, but I still haven't found the right answer yet.

These are my codes related to the problem:

```
    @RestController
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class GCSController {

    private final GCSService gcsService;

    @PostMapping("gcs/upload")
    public ResponseEntity localUploadToStorage(@RequestBody UploadReqDto uploadReqDto) throws IOException {
         BlobInfo fileFromGCS = gcsService.uploadFileToGCS(uploadReqDto);
         return ResponseEntity.ok(fileFromGCS.toString());
  }
 } 


    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class GCSService {

     private final Storage storage;

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     public BlobInfo uploadFileToGCS(UploadReqDto uploadReqDto) throws IOException {


         BlobInfo blobInfo =storage.create(
                 BlobInfo.newBuilder(uploadReqDto.getBucketName(), uploadReqDto.getUploadFileName())
                         .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllAuthenticatedUsers(), Acl.Role.READER))))
                         .build(),
                 new FileInputStream(uploadReqDto.getLocalFileLocation()));

         return blobInfo;
     }

    }
```

UploadReqDto makes constructor, getter for bucketname, uploadFileName and localFilelocation.

This is the maven dependency that I've added for the API:

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: what filesystem structure are you using in GAE? Is this GAE standard or flex?

Comment: It’s GAE standard project.

Comment: GAE standard only [has access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) to /tmp, how are you loading the files in the GAE local storage before trying to upload them to GCS?

Comment: I am trying to upload files in local machine to GCS. Do you have any suggestions that I can try ? Thanks for your kind answer.

Comment: I posted a recommendation that could be useful, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with a solution so here is my answer to my own question:

Fixed it by using signed url for my Goolge Cloud Storage bucket. I was on this problem for a week and figured that there is no proper way to get to your own file path(like C:/users/) when you are running your project on GAE.

Guess this [google doc(uploading objects to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) is only helpful when your project is running locally. So the solution to my problem was to generate a signed URL for my bucket and access to the bucket by it. Here is the link that was helpful: [how to create signed url for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#code-samples)

Thank you to all who answered this question anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java) to upload files from local storage to GAE standard java (click "code samples" tab and "Java"), you can find more information o[n this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage)

Take into consideration that writing to local disk in app engine standard [is limited](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) to /tmp

If you are using a file path of the likes C:/users/.. on code deployed App Engine Java will not be able to find it

Comment: I've already tried this code, but the project still returns java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException.
I guess it is because the google app engine server is not running locally. The problem is that I am trying to upload(create object) a file from my computer(the path is something like C:/users/..) to google cloud storage, and when I run the server on localhost, it creates object perfectly, but when I deploy the project to app engine and run on {project-name}.appspot.com, it fails to find the file from my computer.

Comment: that is correct if you are using a file path of the likes C:/users/.. on code deployed App Engine Java will not be able to find it

Comment: Thanks. just fixed with using signed url for GCS!